# sign into google analytics with alt account

Tags: auto-login, google-analytics

When I try to access google analytics, it always tries to login via my primary login (which is my student gmail account). However, I have my google analytics set up for a different google apps account (me@mydomain.com) and when I try to login, I always end up in the Google Apps Admin Console for mydomain.com. I cannot find any analytics information there.

Is there something I can do to actually log into the analytics website, or have I missed something? Sorry, I know this sounds like a n00b question.

Note: Because I switch between logins regularly, I have set up multiple sign in and have bookmarks that allow me to access the relevant gmail account easily. I would prefer that I didn't have to sign out of all my google accounts in order to just access analytics, because it would disrupt the feng shui of my bookmarks (and I'd need to log into them again - in the correct order!)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in pretty much the same position (one Google account for Analytics and Webmaster Tools and another for my personal Google Apps) and unfortunately the only solution I can suggest is to use a different browser for one of the tasks. I use Chrome for my regular browsing and then pop open IE when I need to access Analytics under my other account. It's not ideal but it's not overly cumbersome and I don't have to keep signing in and out so it is reasonable time-efficient.

I'm hoping that Google keeps up the improvements they started with their multi-account feature and extends this to all their Apps so everything just works a little better!

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for the bad news, but well answered!